# How can I implement StringBuilder and/or call String.FastAllocateString?

Tags: c#, .net, stringbuilder, cil

I was curious to see if I could create an optimized version of `StringBuilder` (to take a stab at speeding it up a little, *as it is currently the bottleneck of one of my applications*).  Unfortunately for me, it seems to make use of "magical" system calls that are not available for me to use (or so it seems).

After decompiling the source code for `System.Text.StringBuilder`, I noticed it makes use of the following *internal* (and therefore uncallable) system call:

```
[SecurityCritical]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
internal static string FastAllocateString(int length);
```

There's also this undocumented attribute that gets used a lot:

```
[ForceTokenStabilization]
```

I was able to replace all calls to `FastAllocateString(n)` with just `String.Empty` and comment out all `[ForceTokenStabilization]` attributes. After doing this, and copy-pasting some methods from other classes, I was actually able to get it to compile. ([complete code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7478004)).

I'd really like to not have to make these two tradeoffs, because I assume they are there for a reason.

- Anyone know a secret ninja alternative way to call `FastAllocateString`?
- Anyone know what `ForceTokenStabilization` really does (and possibly an alternative way to achieve it?)

Comment: FWIW, you *can* call internal methods, using reflection.  Obviously you have to decide if it's worth the smell.

Comment: Why are you building a non-threadsafe version of an already non-threadsafe class?

Comment: Did you mean you were trying to build a thread-safe version? I'm not sure how that would even make sense, a thread-safe stringbuilder would be pretty pointless.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: I guess you're right; I had been looking at the `StringBuilder` code for .NET 2.0, which calls things like `GetThreadSafeString`, which is calling `Thread.InternalGetCurrentThread()`. It looks like the .NET 4.0 code doesn't do this

Comment: Ah yes. Yeah, I think that's gone now with the new linked-list approach, though even there that was a counter to their making something particularly un-threadsafe in an optimisation, so in removing the need to be careful of threads you have to also remove the optimisation (IIRC it was about making `ToString` particular fast in often returning the internal string it was modifying rather than building a new one).

Comment: Microsoft has now released CLR reference source, no more need to decompile (unless to confirm your local implementation). http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs

Comment: yoyo correct however they have not release the source code to their native code (that I know of) eg FastAllocateString which is described here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can call it:

```
var fastAllocate =
            typeof (string).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
                .First(x => x.Name == "FastAllocateString");

var newString = (string)fastAllocate.Invoke(null, new object[] {20});

Console.WriteLine(newString.Length); // 20
```

Note that `FastAllocateString` is a member of `string`..

The Rotor SSCLI distribution internally emits native ASM for the platform the code is running on to allocate a buffer and return the address. I can only assume the official CLR is roughly doing the same.

According to [this link](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Runtime/NgenServicingAttributes@cs/1305376/NgenServicingAttributes@cs), `ForceTokenStabilization` is for:

```
//===========================================================================================================
// [ForceTokenStabilization] - Using this CA forces ILCA.EXE to stabilize the attached type, method or field.
// We use this to identify private helper methods invoked by IL stubs.
//
// NOTE: Attaching this to a type is NOT equivalent to attaching it to all of its methods!
//===========================================================================================================
```

Comment: You'd want to cache the `MethodInfo` for sure. Even so, I wonder if you'd not be faster just to call `new string('\0', 20)` than to call `FastAllocateString` through a `MethodInfo`.

Comment: You're probably right @JonHanna. I suspect there is probably a lot of premature optimization going on here anyway. I just thought I would answer the question though :)

Comment: Yeah, totally worth answering, but worth pointing out that it likely won't be as fast as a compiled-in call to `FastAllocateString` either.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead: thanks for the answer, but it's not premature optimization if it's the bottleneck of your application.  And Jon Hanna's right, this probably won't be very "Fast"

Comment: What does "stabilize the attached type" mean?

Comment: I agree with @JonHanna - The call through Reflection is not very fast. Not a big surprise. I've tested both variants with a cached MethodInfo and a tight loop constructing 10,000,000 strings. With a string length of 20, the constructor was 4x faster, with 100 and 1000 characters, it still was twice as fast. By the way, the MethodInfo can be queried much easier:

`MethodInfo pMethod  = typeof (String).GetMethod ("FastAllocateString", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);`

Comment: (1 of 2) This inspired me to do some benchmarking on .net8 to compare string.Concat, which uses FastAllocateString vs a few different manual implementations which never call the string methods and just do it all via Spans and copying them to a single allocation of a destination Span via `stackalloc`. Benchmark.net showed runtime to be indentical within less than 5% of the more verbose manual implementations vs simply calling string.Concat, whether string.Concat was called with string or span arguments.

Comment: (2 of 2) The only cases that the manual implementations were faster were when needing to concat more strings than string.Concat has an explicit overload for (4 ReadOnlySpans). But, even in that case, the the manual implementation was still a maximum of 8% faster and 5% on average than string.Concat, with 1000 iterations.

Comment: A follow-up thought to my previous comments: There's a possibility that adding `[SkipLocalsInit]` to the manual method with the stackalloc could potentially be slightly faster, by skipping the zeroing of the allocated block. I did not benchmark it with that, as it didn't occur to me at the time. Any improvement from that would scale linearly with length of the allocation. I am not sure, though, if using that attribute on a method using the string methods would result in any difference in them, since FastAllocateString is a black box.